# Is it bad practice to edit your own question to put it to the top of the pile?

Tags: discussion, editing

I just added a new tag to one of my own questions as a test to see would this put the question at the top of the questions sorted by activity and it did.

I don't plan on doing this, I just wanted to see would it actually work.

Is it frowned upon to be editing your own questions just to put them to the top of the pile to gain more publicity and possibly more votes? Or can this be seen as a way of getting attention for a question you really want answered without having to give a bounty?

Comment: I really don't see this as a problem, as long as the edits are useful and it's not repeated frequently just to keep it on top.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say that if it was a blatant attempt to just bump the question to bump it then it would be frowned upon.

If its to legitimately improve the question and properly tag it, this is ok.

I'll personally accept wanting to bump up the question if it hasn't had any attention after a week or so, not sure how everyone else feels about this, however.

Answer (score 3):

As long as it's not spammy, I don't see it as a big deal.  You're better off offering a bounty to get attention though.